# How are human rotaviruses generally transmitted?

Tags: virology

I know rotaviruses are double stranded RNA viruses and i am wondering if the human transmission is similar to the modes of veterinary transmission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faecal-oral transmission. Ref from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotavirus

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you.